# Need help in creating a cloud function to respond to onDisconnect event on a particular node - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need help in writing a Firebase cloud function to respond to onDisconnect event, how can listen to a specific node for disconnection since my client is connecting to a specific node, i am new to cloud function, your help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to achieve something like this
`var amOnline = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/presence/' + userid);
amOnline.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    userRef.onDisconnect().set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    userRef.set(true);
  }
});`
but in cloud function, is it possible, since my client might get disconnected dropping internet connection without updating the node.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct trigger from a user disconnection to triggering a Cloud Function. You would [use the regular Realtime Database functionality for storing presence information in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Then you can trigger Cloud Functions off that database write, with something like:

```
exports.onlineStateChanged = functions.database.ref('/status/{uid}/')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
```

It's quite similar to the solution for [using the Realtime Database to get a presence information into Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#updating_globally).